# Trigger to auto-increment ID based on certain criteria in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I would like to write a trigger so that when a new record comes in, if certain columns of it contains the same content as the previous record, one particular ID column for all existing entries would increase by 1 and the new entry would be 0, and if there is no existing record, the new record is automatically assigned to have ID 0 in that column.

For example, say my existing data is like this:

```
FirstName  LastName  InvoiceID  Amt
-----------------------------------
John        Doe       1         $5
Bill        Jane      0         $6
John        Doe       0         $3
```

Now say I want to insert John Doe with $3.5 of invoice, then the record would automatically becomes:

```
FirstName  LastName  InvoiceID  Amt
-----------------------------------    
John        Doe       1         $5
Bill        Jane      0         $6
John        Doe       2         $3
John        Doe       0         $3.5
```

Now if I need to insert someone new, say Jane Smith for $2, it would become:

```
FirstName  LastName  InvoiceID  Amt
--------------------------------------
John        Doe       1         $5
Bill        Jane      0         $6
John        Doe       2         $3
John        Doe       0         $3.5
Jane        Smith     0         $2
```

May I know how should write such trigger in T-SQL?

Thanks!

Comment: It's almost always better to generate such values whilst `SELECT`ing out of the database, provided you've recorded enough information in the table to allow it to be so constructed (e.g. just have a plain `IDENTITY` column on the table, or record the datetime of each row insert, so that you can work out what order the rows arrived)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever agreed. Stored values in the tables could be faster to retrieve, but trigger could be not so simple - one always have to keep in mind that in the `inserted` table there could be 2 records for John Doe or two records for John and one for Bill

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever My only issue is that this example is a lot more simplified, and in reality I might have multiple programs trying to insert the data almost at the same time and therefore between the time it would take to run the select and the time when the data gets inserted, the data might have been changed.

Comment: @AZhu - I meant to not store the `InvoiceID` column at all - there's no gap between select and insert, because there isn't a select and insert. You just *generate* an `InvoiceID` column at the point at which you want to read it.

Comment: Conceptually, the approach is not solid.  There are a lot of things that can go wrong in rolling your own surrogate key.  There will be concurrency problems, in most isolation levels, and it could make the data unreliable.  I would use a surrogate key (like an identity column) and you can then programmaticly create the logic to produce InvoiceId in your code, or add it as a computed column.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45694913/1271037

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do, rather than having the trigger:

```
create table T (TID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,FirstName varchar(10) not null,LastName varchar(10) not null,Amt decimal(18,4) not null)
go
create view V
as
    select
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FirstName,LastName ORDER BY TID desc) - 1 as InvoiceID,
        Amt
    from
        T
go
```

And then set up your initial data:

```
insert into T(FirstName,LastName,Amt) values
('John','Doe',5),
('Bill','Jane',6)
go
insert into T(FirstName,LastName,Amt) values
('John','Doe',3)
```

And the new John Doe row:

```
insert into T(FirstName,LastName,Amt) values
('John','Doe',3.5)
```

And finally the Jane Smith row:

```
insert into T(FirstName,LastName,Amt) values
('Jane','Smith',2)
```

And then select from the view:

```
FirstName  LastName   InvoiceID            Amt
---------- ---------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------
Bill       Jane       0                    6.0000
Jane       Smith      0                    2.0000
John       Doe        0                    3.5000
John       Doe        1                    3.0000
John       Doe        2                    5.0000
```

And so we have no concern that `InvoiceID` might be incorrect because we never *store* it.

```
select * from V
```

Comment: I just posted a comment above, but you and I are of the same opinion.  This is a much better route to take.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for the response. However I am talking about a huge table here and if I have to create the view on the fly each and every time, it would take a long time, that's why I need to get it in the table as an actual data.

Comment: And I am not inserting everything at once but the data is being continuously inserted.

Comment: @AZhu - how often is the data being *queried*? If data is being inserted "continuously", and every insert (by your method) has to update *every* other row, do you really think you're going to have good overall performance?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Agreed except I don't really care if there is a few seconds of delay in the insertion (since that is not what the end user see), however if there is a long delay in the query, the end user will complain :)