# Identity-like column but based on Group By criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, identity

In my SQL Server 2012 database, I'm creating a "Tasks" table that will have a compound primary key composed of three fields:

```
Issue_ID [int] NOT NULL,
Issue_Sub_ID [int] NOT NULL,
Task_ID [int] NOT NULL
```

`Issue_ID` and `Issue_Sub_ID` are foreign keys to other tables.  In the table I'm creating, there can be many tasks associated with each `Issue_ID` / `Issue_Sub_ID` combination.

What I would like to do is establish a default value for the `Task_ID` column, similar to if I used `IDENTITY(1,1)`, but that will auto-increment based on the `Issue_ID` / `Issue_Sub_ID` group.  For example, the `Task_ID` results would look as follows, given the provided `Issue_ID` / `Issue_Sub_ID` values:

```
Issue_ID     Issue_Sub_ID     Task_ID
========     ============     =======
12345             1              1
12345             1              2
12345             1              3
12345             2              1
12345             2              2
67890             2              1
67890             2              2
67890             2              3
```

I'm familiar with the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Issue_ID, Issue_Sub_ID ORDER BY Issue_ID, Issue_Sub_ID)` possible solution but, as I'd like this column to be a part of the compound primary key of the table, I don't think that will work.

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: how Identity(1,1) will reset? It will go on from 1.. n

Comment: On your Tasks table, how will you correctly relate to the correct task if you're duplicating ``Task_ID``?

Comment: Problem is, `Identity(1,1)` will continue to increment... in my example, `Task_ID` is "1" for `Issue_ID` of "12345" and `Issue_Sub_ID` of "2."  If I had used `Identity(1,1)`, `Task_ID` for that entry would be "4"

Comment: Primary key of the Tasks table will be compound key made up of `Issue_ID`, `Issue_Sub_ID`, and `Task_ID`.  So, each task will be referenced through each of those three values.

Comment: Set default to 0, update via trigger on `insert`

Comment: @JohnHC that won't work. The OP stated that all three columns make up a composite primary key. That approach would prevent multiple rows from being inserted in a single statement.

Comment: I would just use an identity and then either add another persistent column to track the order of tasks or simply use ROW_NUMBER when selecting them.

Comment: @SeanLange Yep, my bad...

Answer (score 9):

I agree with Sean - add an identity column, and then just use a computed column for the task id.
Even though I've answered a question very much like this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277211/database-scheme-autoincrement/43277406#43277406),
I'm not sure about marking this one as a duplicate. The reason for this is that you want to use the `task_id` as a part of the primary key.
However, I'm not sure that's possible, since in order to include a computed column in the primary key it must be `persisted`, and for some reason (I think it's because of the use of a UDF) SQL Server will not allow me to mark it as persisted.
Anyway, here is my proposed solution for this:

First, create a function that will calculate the task id:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GenerateTaskId
(
    @Row_Id int,
    @Issue_Id int,
    @Issue_Sub_Id int
)
RETURNS Int
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM dbo.Tasks
        WHERE Issue_Id = @Issue_Id
        AND Issue_Sub_ID = @Issue_Sub_ID
        AND Row_Id <= @Row_Id
    )
END
GO
```

Then, create the table with the task id as a computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tasks
(
    Row_Id [int] IDENTITY(1,1),
    Issue_ID [int] NOT NULL,
    Issue_Sub_ID [int] NOT NULL,
    Task_Id AS dbo.GenerateTaskId(Row_Id, Issue_Id, Issue_Sub_Id), 
    CONSTRAINT PK_Tasks PRIMARY KEY (Row_Id)
)
GO
```

Now, test it:

```
INSERT INTO Tasks VALUES
(12345, 1),
(12345, 1),
(12345, 1),
(12345, 2),
(12345, 2),
(67890, 2),
(67890, 2),
(67890, 2)

SELECT *
FROM Tasks
```

Results:

```
Row_Id  Issue_ID    Issue_Sub_ID    Task_Id
1       12345       1               1
2       12345       1               2
3       12345       1               3
4       12345       2               1
5       12345       2               2
6       67890       2               1
7       67890       2               2
8       67890       2               3
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/HRSAY3573)

Comment: Zohar, you're the man.  I embedded a call to this in an insert trigger, with an in-memory UDTT there to do the calculations.  Works like a charm.  Thank you!

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)